# Discrete wavelet center frequency

Tags: discrete-signals, wavelet, denoising

I am understanding that mother wavelets have a center frequency. Wavelets are limited in duration and oscillate then decay, so the center frequency is the mid pulse of the wavelet or so.
But my question is, how does the center frequency play a role in noise reduction for example? what does the center frequency affect? does it have to do anything with the resolution of the denoising? and does the center freqeuncy stay the same in discrete wavelets since we do not scale the actual wavelet?

Comment: Would it be possible to cite a specific example of wavelet denoising you might be referring to? Otherwise, shall we assume the typical round trip of decomposing the signal to a set of coefficients and then recomposing through only a subset of those?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the typical decomposition and reconstruction steps. I am trying to understand if it is crucial to know about the center frequency I am using which is why I am wondering if it affects the typical process.